# rdlc ReportViewer fails

Tags: rdlc, reportviewer

When calling `rdlc` preview, I'm getting Error:

> 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: 'DocMapUpdatePanelId' is not a property or an existing field.

ReportViewer version is 12. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same issue I had:
https://forums.asp.net/p/2109211/6098055.aspx

Change your handler in web.config to this:

    `<add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>`